# Web scraper in selenium is too slow and don't how to use other methods

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Hi so this is the code i wrote it gets domain names and their prices it works perfect but is too slow and i want to use scrapy or beautiful soup but don't know how to do it

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
urls = ["https://www.brandbucket.com/styles/6-letter-domain-names?page=1","https://www.brandbucket.com/styles/6-letter-domain-names?page=2"]
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}
driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome()
for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    names = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="domainCardDetail"]//span')
    for value in names:
         print(value.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(...)
```

to wait only until a specific element is loaded? See [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Comment: the code i wrote above works good but is extremely slow so i used bs4 but it returns nothing like it can't find the element

Comment: You need to understand why the chromedriver runs slow. Internet connection? My guess would be that loading the page takes long. You can make that faster by using `wait`